# overflowing divs in android chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, overflow

I've made this simple [pen](http://codepen.io/vahidseo/pen/yHArj), but it has overflow problem in android chrome browser. Do you know how I can fix it?

Those two green divs which are supposed to be hills, drop out of the main round div.

Comment: can you add an image which shows the bug ? I also notice it resize when I hover on the circle, is that ok ?

Comment: Here's an image: [Image](http://i.share.pho.to/31bb659c_o.jpeg). The hover animation is fine.